# Lipsum text generator for an index

Tags: packages

Is there something like `lipsum` package but for generating an index?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with "analytic index"? Some more information would be great.

Comment: No package that I know does; however, version 0.6 of `kantlipsum` will feature index generation.

Comment: I removed "analytic" from the question. In Italian it's "Indice analitico", while in English it's just "Index" as there's no confusion with the table of contents, which is "Indice" in Italian.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Version 0.6 of `kantlipsum`, just uploaded to CTAN, has a new feature: the `index` option will add an index entry for each paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[index]{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\kant

\kant[20-30]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The index will be like in the following picture

[image]

Comment: I can not update to version 0.6. In TeXLive manager I have  put this link: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet Is it correct to download the update?